# How to setup a test HTTPS site under IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, https

I have a WCF service that I would like to run on https:// how can I setup a test site on local host for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic this, to a certain extent with a self signed certificate. How you get one depends on your version of IIS - IIS7 has [built in functionality](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) for this, IIS6 needs you to use [makecert](http://codeforeternity.com/blogs/technology/archive/2008/02/15/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-iis-6-0-and-windows-server-2003.aspx).